# Add marker to all gyms nearby

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-places-api

After looking through the documentation for both the Google Maps Android API and the Google Places Android API, I couldn't find if it's possible to add a marker to all places in a category in a specific range.

Question: Is is possible to put a marker on all gyms in a range of 15 kilometers of my current location? And is it possible to get extra information about those gyms using the Google Places API?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the request [Place Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search?hl=en) of the Google Places API Web Service.

For example, the link bellow (with a valid API key) will give you all the "gym" places within a 15km radius of the point (-33.8670522,151.1957362) in a JSON format:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=15000&types=gym&key=API_KEY

Then, do a loop to add a marker for each entry.